# Owncloud running Apache with Nginx as Proxy

Tags: nginx, web-server, proxy, reverse-proxy, owncloud

I'm currently working on running our own Owncloud (version 9). I've done this several times with Apache but I'm having trouble configuring it with Nginx in the front as a Proxy.

**Nginx config**

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        server_name example.com;

    index index.php index.html;

    ssl_certificate /path/ssl.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/ssl.key;
    ssl_dhparam /path/dh.pem;
    ssl_buffer_size 8k;
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_cache builtin:1000 shared:SSL:50m;
    ssl_session_tickets off;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /path/ssl.crt;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=300s;
    resolver_timeout 10s;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubdomains; preload";

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!DSS';
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }
}
```

**Apache Config**

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerAdmin email@example.com
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/owncloud

    <Directory /var/www/owncloud>
        Options +FollowSymLinks
        Options -Indexes
        AllowOverride All
        SetEnv HOME /var/www/owncloud
        SetEnv HTTP_HOME /var/www/owncloud
        SetEnv MOD_X_SENDFILE_ENABLED 1
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**Owncloud config - /var/www/owncloud/config/config.php**

```
<?php
$CONFIG = array (
  'updatechecker' => false,
  'instanceid' => 'xxxxxxxx',
  'passwordsalt' => 'xxxxxxxx',
  'secret' => 'xxxxxxxx',
'overwritehost' => 'example.com:8080',
'overwriteprotocol' => 'https',
'overwritewebroot' => '/',
'proxy' => 'localhost',
'trusted_proxies' => array('192.168.0.2', '127.0.0.1'),
'forwarded_for_headers' => array('HTTP_X_FORWARDED', 'HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'),
  'trusted_domains' => 
  array (
    0 => 'example.com',
  ),
  'datadirectory' => '/not/in/default/data',
  'overwrite.cli.url' => 'https://example.com',
  'dbtype' => 'mysql',
  'version' => '9.0.1.3',
  'dbname' => 'dbname',
  'dbhost' => 'dbhost',
  'dbtableprefix' => 'oc_',
  'dbuser' => 'oc_administrator',
  'dbpassword' => 'xxxxxx',
  'logtimezone' => 'UTC',
  'installed' => true,
);
```

I am able to access the site properly if I don't use Nginx. But if I do, the page will load with no styles. All of the request are getting 404 responses.

I think there is something wrong with my Nginx proxy config or my Owncloud config. I've read this https://doc.owncloud.org/server/8.0/admin_manual/configuration_server/config_sample_php_parameters.html but I don't know if I'm doing the Owncloud config right.

Thanks guys!

## EDIT

Definitely **not** caused by *APACHE CONFIG* or *OWNCLOUD CONFIG*. There is an issue with **JavaScript (.js) or CSS (.css) files not served properly** - [link](https://doc.owncloud.org/server/9.0/admin_manual/installation/nginx_configuration.html).

Comment: Why are you using Nginx and Apache - what do you hope to achieve by adding Nginx? Please post access and error logs for all products for one attempt to access the server, a curl or hit. If you're sure the request doesn't make it past Nginx obviously don't post those logs, but you could show requests either side as a sanity test.